# Add button styles to wordpress editor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am creating a wordpress theme and I want to have some preset button styles to choose from.

In the wordpress editor the button styles are limited to 'Fill' and 'Outline', how do I add my own styles in this list?

I see there is a `button/block.json` in the core files where it lists the available styles. How do I override this in my theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by exploring the `wp.blocks` JavaScript API:

Add `editor.js` in your theme directory with the following contents:

```js
wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle('core/button', {
    name: 'example-button',
    label: 'Example Button Style'
});
```

Then define your styles via the following CSS class name for the *WordPress* Admin **content editor**:

Add `editor.css` in your theme directory:

```css
.wp-block-button.is-style-example-button .wp-block-button__link {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then define your styles via the following CSS class for the **public user facing theme**:

Add these to your theme CSS files (*style.css*) the one you output to the user:

```css
.is-style-example-button .wp-block-button__link {
    background-color: red;
}
```

At the end you need to register your scripts. Add this to your `functions.php` file:

```php
// Enqueue Block Editor styles
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'example_editor_styles');
function example_editor_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('example-editor', get_template_directory_uri() . '/editor.css', array('wp-edit-blocks'));
}
// Enqueue Block Editor script
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'example_block_enqueues');
function example_block_enqueues() {
    wp_enqueue_script('your-theme-editor-customisations', get_template_directory_uri() . '/editor.js', array('wp-edit-post', 'wp-blocks', 'wp-dom-ready'), '', true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to do it in the theme.json.

Comment: Can this be done for the actual page? I would like to have some predefined classes to optionally add to the body, per page.